# azure sql connectivity from local sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, windows-firewall, azure-sql-server

I am working with azure based application. In which, I need to get connected with azure sql server. I had already configured firewall setting on azure portal for my IP address. But still even when I tried to get connected to azure sql server, it never gets connect at the very first time. When I try to connect it more than two times then it gets connected.

This problem is also with application level connectivity, when i try to run the application on visual studio same happens.

I had researched a lot regarding this specific problem but didn't get any solution yet. I always get network related error Error Code : 53.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to connect to the server? Your App or locally hosted SQL Server? What is throwing the error?

Comment: @DanRediske-MSFT I am getting network related error with local sql server management studio at first time then it gets connected. Same happens when i try to do with visual studio IDE.

Comment: But only the first time?

Comment: yes only the first time..

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like a local network issue.

When your application is deployed onto an Azure resource (App service, VM, etc.) does it get a similar connection error?

Every Azure SQL Server has a firewall, you need to create a client IP rule but also to allow access to the Azure service.